# How do I fix the partitions and dual boot with Windows 10 + Ubuntu 19.04?

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, partitioning, multi-boot, grub

My Dell laptop came with Windows 10. I tried to dual boot with Ubuntu 18.04, created partitions and lost my Windows installation. This is what I mean by lost: When I enter Windows from grub it shows the Dell icon and displays "Diagnosing your PC, Repairing your PC" at the bottom. Then it enters the blue Windows environment with options including "Repair and Fix" "Restart" etc. But none of them work. The Microsoft Reserved partition shows the following error on GParted:

[image: Microsoft Reserved Partition Error]

Unable to detect file system! Possible reasons are:
- The file system is damaged
- The file system is unknown to GParted
- There is no file system available (unformatted)
- The device entry /dev/nvme0n1p2 is missing

These are all my partitions on GParted: [image: Partitions]

My Ubuntu installation works perfectly. I have backed up all my files and created a bootable USB with Ubuntu 19. I have downloaded Windows 10 Disc Images from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO). Can I use this file (Win10_1903_V1_English_x64.iso size:4.9GB) to create a bootable Windows USB? I really need to install and use Windows 10. How do I fix my partitions and successfully dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu?

Thank you!

GRUB
 [image: My GRUB]